# Issue found after running flutter doctor command: "Please install the "Desktop development with C++" Is it necessary to resolve this issue?

Tags: flutter

I am getting this issue when I run `flutter doctor`

```
 Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.47)
    X Visual Studio 2019 or later is required.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
```

Is it necessary for me to solve the above issue before I can run flutter on my android studio?

Comment: why don't you just update your vs code?

Comment: Because it's showing 7.45GB of space needed. And I have limited data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary for me to solve the above issue before I can run flutter on my android studio?

No. This is *only* necessary to solve this issue if you want to *develop Windows* apps as it requires Visual Studio to be installed.

---

If you want to solve this issue. Download Visual Studio and when installing, under the "Workloads" tab, click on "Desktop development with C++".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not needed to run flutter on android studio. The only reason it's needed is for windows development with flutter, so if you're not going to take that path then there is no need to install VS Studio.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up for me